# Esse assembly não permite chamadores parcialmente confiáveis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

Eu tenho meu projeto, e nele eu tenho um *dll* para acessar alguns métodos, em desenvolvimento funciona normalmente, mas no ambiente de homologação esta dando esta msg:

> "Esse assembly não permite chamadores parcialmente confiáveis. "

O que pode ser?

**Obs:** Já adicionei o `"[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]"` no `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: Descobri o problema, mudaram a política de hospedagem.
obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é inserir no `Web.config` o seguinte:

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
```

O erro acontece porque a aplicação pode estar configurada para *Medium Trust*.

Se ainda assim não funcionar, mude as referências, se houver:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

Para `Copy Local` **True** nas propriedades da referência. Experimente aí publicar novamente.

Comment: Deu erro "Esta seção de configuração não pode ser usada neste caminho. Isso ocorre quando o administrador do site bloqueia o acesso a essa seção usando <location allowOverride="false"> de um arquivo de configuração herdado.
"

Comment: @RenanFBossa Coloquei mais umas dicas.

Comment: Mesmo erro mencionado acima... :/